# Are eigenstates normal to their derivatives?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, normalization

Suppose we have a Hamiltonian $H_{\lambda}$ which depends on a continuous parameter $\lambda$, and which has a discrete, non-degenerate spectrum $\{\left|n,\lambda\right> : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for each value of $\lambda$.  Take each $\left|n,\lambda\right>$ to vary smoothly with $\lambda$.

**Question:**  Is $\left<n,\lambda\right|\partial_{\lambda}\left|n,\lambda\right> = 0$?

It's easy to see that 
\begin{eqnarray}
0 & = & \partial_{\lambda} 1 \\
& = & \partial_{\lambda} \left<n,\lambda | n,\lambda\right> \\
& = & \left(\partial_{\lambda} \left<n,\lambda\right|\right) \left|n,\lambda\right> + \left<n,\lambda\right| \partial_{\lambda} \left|n,\lambda\right> \\
& = & \left(\left<n,\lambda\right| \partial_{\lambda} \left|n,\lambda\right>\right)^* + \left<n,\lambda\right| \partial_{\lambda} \left|n,\lambda\right> \\
& = & 2\Re\{\left<n,\lambda\right| \partial_{\lambda} \left|n,\lambda\right>\},
\end{eqnarray}
but how to show that the imaginary part is zero?  Or perhaps there is a counter-example to show that it is not?

Answer (score 3):

In general, the imaginary part is not zero.  This is due to the fact that eigenvectors are only defined up to an overall phase.  So another perfectly good eigenbasis of $H_{\lambda}$ is $\{e^{i\phi(\lambda)} \left|n,\lambda\right>\}$, where $\phi(\lambda)$ is an arbitrary smooth function.  We have

\begin{eqnarray}
\left<n,\lambda\right|e^{-i\phi(\lambda)} \partial_{\lambda} e^{i\phi(\lambda)} \left|n,\lambda\right> & = & \left<n,\lambda\right|e^{-i\phi(\lambda)} i\phi'(\lambda) e^{i\phi(\lambda)} \left|n,\lambda\right> + \left<n,\lambda\right| \partial_{\lambda} \left|n,\lambda\right> \\
& = & i\phi'(\lambda) + \left<n,\lambda\right| \partial_{\lambda} \left|n,\lambda\right>
\end{eqnarray}

which shows that we can produce a basis for which $\Im\{\left<n,\lambda\right|\partial_{\lambda}\left|n,\lambda\right>\}$ is totally arbitrary.